# Change font size and style in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Where is the setting to change the font size and font type in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> Inside *Environment* -> *Fonts and Colors*:

[image: Screenshot of the options dialog in Visual Studio, invoked by menu command Tools/Options.]

Comment: surprisingly _not_ under Text Editor.

Answer (score 4):

It is in menu *Tools* / *Options* / *Environment* / *Fonts and Colors*.

Answer (score 4):

You can import (menu *Tools* / *Options* / *Import and Export Settings*) studiostyles from `http://studiostyl.es/schemes`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Environment -> *Fonts And Colors*. Also, if you are bored with the old themes with Visual Studio and other things, you can change the themes of Visual Studio.

I have [a web page](http://frickinsweet.com/tools/) which will create themes for Visual Studio, and you just need to import those things into your environment.