# I am looking for a suggestion for the font style in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have tried several different font style setting in vs2008 so that I can easily distinguish between parenthesis and brackets. { ( ) } .

I have not found a font that is good at parenthesis and brackets but also comfortable to look at all day.

Lucida Console is what I have settled on for now, but can anyone recommend one that they think is easier on the eyes?

(To change the setting, go to tools->options-> environment-> fonts and colors . see stackoverflow: 
[Change font size and style in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836310/change-font-size-and-style-in-visual-studio-2008))

Comment: Courier New or Consolas (the 2010 default) both work fine for me. Do you suffer from impaired vision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a font that it nice to read, you shouldn't limit yourself to monospaced fonts.

Personally I use Verdana at the moment.

Comment: @Widor: Hm... perhaps for Javascript? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS 2012, you can use open type fonts (more fonts):

Try Inconsolata: http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html
Download: http://www.google.com/webfonts/download?kit=CNj0Ze1H6w4FVgc32wmZS4fD-WQWLbF4rYwcBGowFYY

Another one to try is Droid Sans Mono http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Droid-Sans-Mono
See also http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-sans-mono-great-coding-font

**Update 1:**

Also try the ones in http://damieng.com/blog/tag/coding-fonts
especially Envy Code R http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released